# Why my console does not shows types errors in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-tsc

I recently started a vue3 project and decided to use TypeScript. Once I had studied some basics I intentionally made a typing mistake but no error appeared:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

interface Fichier {
  nom: string,
  taille: number,
  contenu: object,
  isLoaded: boolean,

}

let itv: Fichier = {
  nom: "Fichier 1",
  taille: 45,
  contenu: [],
  isLoaded: false,
  etat: []
}

console.log(itv)
```

I expected the console to show an error but nothing appears.

Comment: What errors? Consider explaining the problem.

Comment: I think OP is expecting that having extra `etat` property should cause an error. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAQC2NZBvAWAChlkQB7AWwC5kBnMKUAcwBpjSw5gAbHiWiACulAEbR2JZAnLgIw2uVEArCAjCTSwOgBlycACYQDtUeXL84IScQC+xYvzDJgYAG610WHFGQBefA4yKloAIi9sXABGUM1kLl5+WgAWAFY4mTkFZABtAF047T1DY1p4HjoIOIguMFp8uwciTLoLCAA6HnJmAApXNwBKYiA

Comment: Type Errors are supposed to be thrown during compile time. Types are for your IDE. Your browser only knows/understands/executes JavaScript. At that point, all types are gone.

Comment: Typescript tooling depends on IDE you are using. Some IDEs (e.g. VS Code) have built-in tools for type checking, while others don't.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the `<script>` tag you're working in a browser.

Browsers don't run TypeScript. TypeScript needs to be transpiled to JavaScript to run in a browser.

To get a feel for the language without setting up a local environment you can try the TypeScript playground. Here's a link with the code you posted:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAQC2NZBvAKGWRAHsBbALmQGcwpQBzAGiOTDmABsuJqQAruQBG0VsQSlwEQdVLCAVhARhxyYDQAypOABMIu6sNKlecEKwIBfAgV5h1YAG7V0WHFGQBefGzJVkACI3bFwARkC1Dm5eagAWAFY1SWlZZABtAF01DW09A2p4LhoINQgOMGos61sUmlMIADouUkYACmBnAEogA)

It clearly shows an error:
[image]

Another way is using an editor like VS Code, which shows errors immediately without transpiling to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

In your case console.log **should not throw an error**, **the compiler should throw an error and you should not be able to run the app**. Probably something with your compiler is wrong if you are able to run the app.

I would not suggest that you add typescript in application like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
```

From what I can see you have been following the **[script setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#basic-syntax)**  from the official documentation which will not add a compiler to the IDE and will not prompt errors like you suggested. I would suggest you to:

**To install and setup typescript compiler properly in order to work (see the last line for official documentation).**

Install the TypeScript package:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript
```

Create a tsconfig.json file in your project:

```
npx tsc --init
```

Edit vue.config.js file to configure the TypeScript compiler:

```
 module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> the picture below is example when you have proper typescript compiler (you will receive complilation error)

[image]

**For full configuration please follow the [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html):**

Comment: This recommendation doesn't serve a good purpose without knowing the OP's setup. It's safe to assume that TS is already handled, considering that TS component presumably works.